# ¿Como enseñar un formulario segun la opción seleccionada de una lista en html?

Tags: html, entrada, type

Soy algo nuevo con el código Html así que me gustaría pediros un poco de ayuda.

Tengo 3 listas con opciones, encadenadas entre ellas mediante funciones de JavaScript, para mostrar opciones según la opción que elijas.
Mi intención es, que después de elegir la opción en la 3 lista, me salga un formulario para rellenar.

1. ¿Cómo gestiono esto? ¿Tengo que poner los `labels` y los `inputs type` en `hidden` y luego con una función en JavaScript mostrarlos? Si alguien pudiera hacerme un ejemplo estaría agradecido.
2. La otra opción que quiero, es que los `labels` no sean estaticos. Es decir, si para una opción el primer campo necesito un nombre, el `label` pondra "nombre" pero para la segunda, quiero que el `label` que salga sea "Email". Si se pudieran cambiar las id también sería un puntazo.

Voy a poner el código que tengo.

Formulario que quiero mostrar:

```html
<form id="formulario">
<label for ="nombre"></label>
<input type ="text" name = "nombre" id ="nombre" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre"></br>

<label for="asunto"></label>
<input type="text" name="Asunto" id="asunto" placeholder="Asunto"></br>

<label for="asunto"></label>
<input type="text" name="Correo" id="correo" placeholder="Correo para recibir respuesta"></br>

<label for="mensaje"></label>
<textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder= "Escribe tu consulta"></textarea>
<br>
<a HREF="mailto:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?subject"> <input type="submit"> </a>
</form>
```

Quiero que este formulario se muestre y cambien los `labels` cuando llegue aquí. Ya llamo a esta función cuando escojo la 3º opción.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 function mostrarformulario(id){
  var a = document.getElementById("lista3").value;
  if (a == "Alta usuario")
   {
   }
}
</script>
```

Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Hola David, bienvenido a StackOverflow. Para que alguien pueda echarte una mano con tu problema es necesario que muestres el código con lo que tienes hecho, puedes [edit] tu pregunta y añadirlo. Si no conoces como funciona el sitio te recomiendo leer [ask] y hacer el [tour].

Comment: Voy a ello. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes el formulario en la página y está oculto por css con `'style="display: none;"'`, lo puedes mostrar con `JQuery`

```
function mostrarformulario(id){ 
  $("#formulario").show(); 
}
```

o `JavaScript`

```
function mostrarformulario(id){ 
  document.getElementById("formulario").style.display = "block";
}
```

Otra opción es tener el formulario en otro archivo y traerlo por `ajax`, para eso lo que tendrías es un div dentro del cual vas a poner el formulario.

```
function mostrarformulario(id){
  $.ajax({ 
        url: 'url donde está el form',
        data: { datos si necesitas enviar al form para mostrar },
        success: function(data) { 
            $('#midiv').html(data);         
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No lo tengo oculto en css. Como lo implemento? Esta dentro de un <section id="main"> , <div class = "contenedor", <form id = formulario >.

¿Como tengo que declararlo en css? ¿Así?

.contenedor #formulario{
 display: none;
}

Comment: <form id="formulario" style="display: none;"> directamente o creas una clase en tu archivo css con este estilo y la aplicas en la etiqueta.

Comment: No me acaba de funcionar. La parte de esconder si que funciona, pero la parte de mostrar no se porque. No me muestra ningun error mi editor.

Comment: Lo tengo!!! El error es que formulario en "JavaScript" debe de ir así 'formulario' (entre comillas simples). Muchas gracias!

Comment: Es verdad, se me fueron las comillas, sorry

Comment: Noooo! Comilla simple!!! document.getElementById('formulario').style.display = "block";

Comment: Pueden ser dobles o simples